# Accessing package controllers in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have created a package following the ["Creating a Package" instructions in the Laravel 4 documentation](http://four.laravel.com/docs/packages#creating-a-package). After creating the package I have created a "controllers" folder and a routes file. The new file structure is:

```
/src
    /Vendor
        /Package
            PackageServiceProvider.php
    /config
    /controllers
    /lang
    /migrations
    /views
    routes.php
/tests
/public
```

I added the routes file to the boot portion of the package service provider:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->package('vendor/package');
    include __DIR__ . '/../../routes.php';
}
```

Then added a basic route to the routes file:

```
Route::get('/package', function() {
    return "Package route test";
});
```

Visiting my application at the specified route (app.dev/package) returns the expected:

```
Package route test
```

Then adding a basic controller call to the route (using the default Laravel controller, "HomeController") works:

```
Route::get('/package', 'HomeController@showWelcome');
```

I then followed [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14667793/200518) for setting up the controller for the package. I added the src/controllers folder to the composer classmap, then I dumped the autoloader and checked vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php and found the class is successfully loaded by composer:

```
<?php

// autoload_classmap.php generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(__DIR__);
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'HomeController' => $baseDir . '/src/controllers/HomeController.php',
);
```

Now I added the new package controller to the route using the namespace:

```
Route::get('/package', 'Vendor\Package\Controllers\HomeController@showWelcome');
```

but this produces an error about not finding the class:

```
ReflectionException: Class Vendor\Package\Controllers\HomeController does not exist
```

I've also tried calling it using the package name:

```
Route::get('/package', 'Package::HomeController@showWelcome');
```

which produces the same error:

```
ReflectionException: Class Vendor\Package\Controllers\HomeController does not exist
```

No matter what I try the package cannot access its own controller, which composer confirms is loaded (by viewing vendor/package/autoload_classmap.php).

Any ideas? I'm not sure if the issue is composer not loading the class, I'm not sure where to start with debugging the problem. I've created another package and repeated the steps here and get the same problem.

I can access the package views from both the package and the app, eg:

```
View::make('package::view');
```

The problem seems to be between composer loading the controller and Laravel being able to access it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The mistake was including the controllers path in the route. I had the following:

```
Route::get('/package', 'Vendor\Package\Controllers\HomeController@showWelcome');
```

The correct usage is:

```
Route::get('/package', 'Vendor\Package\HomeController@showWelcome');
```

With the namespace included in the controller:

```
namespace Vendor\Package;
```

Controller should extend illuminate:

```
\Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Controller
```

Still can't use the package name (eg: Package::HomeController@showWelcome), but I can using the namespace. yay.

Problem solved.

Comment: I'm just having a play with Laravel 4 and encountered this issue. Do you really need to add every class to the vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php file? You would think it would be able to find these classes without this wouldn't you?

Comment: @neilcrookes For performance reasons composer generates a flat class map of all the classes, this file is auto generated and it's a very bad idea to edit it manually for anything but a quick test. It's generated using the information in your composer.json file. See http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload

Answer (score 6):

You may try edit your Vendor/Package/composer.json and insert the controllers dir to autoload/classmap:

```
....
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "src/migrations",
        "src/controllers",
        "src/models"
    ],
    "psr-0": {
        "Package\\Controller": "src/"
    }
}
....
```

After that, open your terminal and from your package root dir do a **composer dump-autoload**

Works for me...

Comment: For as far as I know and experienced this will not work for vendor packages but only for packages in your workbench. Try deleting a composer.json file in a vendor package and dump-autoload, it won't matter anything since all the data is loaded from the composer.lock file. You could edit the autoload_classmap.php. If you want to know what's happening behind the scene, check the composer.lock file and autoload_classmap.php file they give a good insight in the mechanics. Please correct me if I'm wrong!

Answer (score 2):

have a look into this  git article might be of help
https://github.com/jaiwalker/setup-laravel4-package

Comment: Thanks for the "Using a controller" section! Adding the controllers to the classmap solved my problem.