# How can I access global classes from within a package?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I created a package which also contains his own controller files and also a router.php file.

My problem is that i can't access anyone of the main classes like `Schema` or `View`.

I always get a Error: Class not Found error.

Comment: You're going to have to post some code in order for someone to help you properly.

Comment: I dont know which code should be helpful here cause its a general problem. I just need to know what i need todo that i cnan access those classes inside a package.

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948329/accessing-package-controllers-in-laravel-4).

Comment: That does not have anything to do with my question :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using namespaces in your package, which you should be. As a result, you need to precede global classes with a backslash to access them. For example, `View::make()` becomes `\View::make()`.

Alternatively, you could import the Facades:

```
<?php
namespace Your\Namespace;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

//...

View::make($view, $data);
```

See the [PHP namespace FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php).