# Laravel::Calling Package Controller in Package Route

Tags: laravel, package, laravel-routing

I have a problem with laravel and need some help.

1. I made a package via artisan and want to call controllers from package via routes in packages.
2. I create a dashboard folder in packages controllers and file DashboardControllers.
3. I dont have any more idea how to call that controller and how to set the NAMESPACES for that controller
4. Question: Is it posible to make a model in package and how to do it and call it if can?
5. Question2: Is it posible to controllers can extends Controller main in Laravel and how to do it?

Path to package goes `ROOT/workbench/ibs/admin/src/route.php`

Hire is my route code form package last what I input in it:

```
Route::group( array('prefix' => 'administrator'/*, 'before' => 'auth'*/ ), function(){
    //Route::get('/', function(){ return 'admin'; });
    //Route::get('/', array('uses' => 'Ibs\Admin\Src\Controllers\Dashboard\DashboardController@index') );
    //Route::get('/', 'Workbench\Ibs\Admin\Controllers\Dashboard\DashboardController@index');
});
```

How to call a stupid controller. 
Path to controller is:

```
ROOT/workbench/ibs/admin/src/controller/Dashboard/DashboardController.php
```

---

Sorry I find a solution it takes about four ours

I didnt use a master controller in package  I combine some solutions from hire:

[Accessing package controllers in Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948329/accessing-package-controllers-in-laravel-4?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you may need to put a backslash **\** at the beginning of your namespaces to indicate that the path is absolute rather than relative.

Like this ...

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'administrator', 'before' => 'auth'), function(){
   Route::get('/', function(){ return 'admin'; });
   Route::get('/', array('uses'=>'\Ibs\Admin\Src\Controllers\Dashboard\DashboardController@index') );
   Route::get('/', '\Workbench\Ibs\Admin\Controllers\Dashboard\DashboardController@index');
```

});