# Controller class in Laravel 4.2 vendor/package/src/controllers directory not found

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

Similarly to [this poster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948329/accessing-package-controllers-in-laravel-4), I am trying to use controllers living in the Laravel vendor folder. (I have followed all the suggestions given in that answer and several other similar ones.) As a simplified case, consider a Laravel vendor project directory shaped like this:

```
    vendor
        marvel
            avengers
                composer.json
                composer.lock
                src
                    controllers
                        HulkController.php
                    Marvel
                        Avengers
                            AvengersServiceProvider.php
                    routes.php
```

I run composer dump-autoload in both the project directory and the Laravel root directory, but when I run "php artisan routes" I get this complaint:

```
{"error":{"type":"ReflectionException","message":
"Class Marvel\\Avengers\\HulkController does not exist",
"file":"C:\\wamp\\www\\marvel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\
Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerInspector.php","line":28}}
```

On the other hand, if I **move "HulkController.php" into the src/Marvel/Avengers directory** (alongside "AvengersServiceProvider.php") and dump the autoloads again, then "php artisan routes" is happy and **routes to HulkController work**.

I have added src/controllers to the classmap in the composer.json file, so I don't think that's the problem:

```
{
  "name": "marvel/avengers",
  "description": "Earth's Mightiest Heroes",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Stan Lee"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "illuminate/support": "4.2.*"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "src/controllers"
    ],
    "psr-0": {
      "Marvel\\Avengers": "src/"
    }
  }
}
```

I personally don't mind keeping my controller classes deeper in the tree if that's what it takes, but that doesn't appear to be the convention, so I think I must be missing something. I'd appreciate any ideas. Happy to post additional parts of the code and config files if that would help. Thanks.

Comment: try switching the psr-0 to psr-4

Comment: Hmmm... Now it's telling me it can't find my service provider class.

Comment: look at the answer provided by Seer, its more in depth. Also check out [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/battle-autoloaders-psr-0-vs-psr-4/) to see differences between PSR-0 and PSR-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your namespace doesn't not match what you're telling Composer to autoload. You're saying "my source folder is `src/`", then saying "`HulkController` is in the `Marvel\Avengers` namespace, which you've just said is... `src/`. Then you have the controller in the controllers folder - which is *not* where you said it was, hence it is not found.

Moving the controller to the `src/` folder works, because that's exactly where you said it should be.

If you change the namespace to `Marvel\Avengers\Controllers\HulkController`, capitalise the controllers folder name, and then update wherever you're referencing that controller to that namespace, then it could work.

An alternative is to switch to using PSR-4 instead of PSR-0, as PSR-0 makes these assumptions about your directory structure where PSR-4 does not.

You can see more about this here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md

Comment: Thanks for the link; I will read up on psr-4. 

To be clear, `HulkController` works when it's in `src\Marvel\Avengers`, but does **not** work when it's in `src\controllers`.

Comment: Try and set your PSR-0 namespace to `Marvell\\Avengers\\ ` with the 2 slashes at the end too. See if that makes it work with just `src/` instead.

Comment: Accepting this answer, since I got further using PSR-4 than by any other method. Thanks for your help and my apologies for the long lag in response.