# Auto load controllers in a custom package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

Ok so I am finally getting around to building an application in Laravel, hopefully in the correct way. I am assuming that using packages to bundle core modules such as 'User', 'Admin' e.t.c is the correct future proof way of doing things.

Anyway, I am working on my User package and well running into trouble adding my controllers. I keep getting the

```
Class RegistrationController does not exist
```

error from Laravel. As the error suggests it cannot find the class RegistrationController in my package from the package routes file:

```
Route::get('user/register', 'RegistrationController@create')->before('guest');
Route::post('user/register', ['as' => 'registration.store', 'uses' => 'RegistrationController@store']);
```

And here is the start of my controller:

```
<?php namespace Vendorname\Package\Controllers;

    class RegistrationController extends \BaseController {
```

My controllers are located in Vendorname/Package/src/controllers and my packages composer file's autoload looks like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "src/migrations",
        "src/controllers"
    ],
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your controller is called `Vendorname\Package\Controllers\RegistrationController`, not `RegistrationController`.

Comment: Try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416608/package-controllers-in-laravel-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `routes.php` file in your package and register your routes there.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Although I had tried this before I failed to composer update which seemed to solve the error. As this is the only answer that's worked I will accept it :)